# Landing Page is not working

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to create a sample landing page (using SFMC landing page function) which will have a form fields for user to type-in and all those information will be saved in Data extension.

So i created a very simple form;

```
<html>
    <form id="myForm" method="post" action="http://pages.abc.com/page.aspx?QS=1234">
        <input type="hidden" name="Email" value="%%Email%%" />
        <input type="hidden" name="PolicyNumber" value="%%PolicyNumber%%" /><br />
        <input type="text" name="Q1A" value="Q1A" />Question 1:
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</html>
```

I kept email and policynumber hidden because I want these two should be automatically grabbed from sendable DE which is Contacts.

Then i create another landing page which should transport data from above form to DE.

```
%%[ 
    set @PolicyNumber = RequestParameter("PolicyNumber")
    set @Email = RequestParameter("Email")
Set @Q1A = RequestParameter("Q1A")
    InsertData("SURVEYRESPONSEDE","PolicyNumber",@PolicyNumber,"Email",@Email,"Q1A",@Q1A)
]%%
```

In an email body I have this code view a form...

```
<a title="MyPage" href="%%=MicrositeURL(99214)=%%" alias="ThisAlias" conversion="false">Click to unsubscribe</a>
```

Now after all that I just simply run above form as subscriber preview to see if everything is working or not.. It does work but in email and policy number fields it did not automatically parse original values. For those two fields in DE it's showing email and policynumber as values...

Any solution

Comment: Are you using Friendly/Personalized URLs ? This is required in order to use personalization strings in a landing page. https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/landing_pages/friendly_and_personalized_urls/

Comment: ok, so you mean I have to parse all declared field names into URL? So final url may look like this....

http://pages.abc.com/page.aspx?QS=1234?email=%%email%%&PolicyNumber=%%PolicyNumber%%&Q1A=%%Q1A%%

Comment: if you do not link to the page via CloudPagesURL link, MicrositeURL link or you use personalized URLS - you would need to pass the key via parameter and then use lookups to gather the rest of the info in AMPscript.

Comment: I am not an expert ...in which URL i have to pass those values and where do i use lookup function, is it suppose to be in landing page where I am using insertdata?

Comment: The parameter values, or ampscript functions would be used to pass the info to the page hosting the webcollect form - this would then be where you grab or lookup the data. Here is more info on lookup function: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookup.htm

Comment: So in email body I made a code something like this; 

<a href="http://pages.insurance.plymouthrock.com/page.aspx?QS=1234?email=%%Email%%&policynumber=%%PolicyNumber%%">UnSub</a>

But now I am getting the error "The page you have requested is unavailable! Please try your link again. The content for this link may no longer be available."